# How can I validate my control on condition using abstract validators?

Tags: angular, typescript

one of my controls is a bool and if that control is true i want the two of my another controls to be required else they can be null.

```
const controls = [
            {name: "bool", control: new FormControl(''), validators: []},
            {name: "firstName", control: new FormControl(''), validators: ???},
            {name: "lastName", control: new FormControl(''), validators: ???},
```

Comment: Hi, so when you want to call validators?

Comment: when my control "bool" gives "true" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cross validate: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms

Or use regex like:

```js
controls.get('bool').value === true ? Validators.required : null
```

Or set them programmatically

```js
if (controls.get('bool').value === true) {
controls['firstName'].setValidators([Validators.required])
}
```

Comment: This expression is not callable.   Type 'AbstractControl' has no call signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do something like the following

```
controls.get('bool').valueChanges.subscribe((value)=>{
    if(value){
    controls.get('firstName).setValidators([Validators.required])
    controls.get('lastName).setValidators([Validators.required])
    return
    }
    controls.get('firstName).removeValidators([Validators.required])
    controls.get('lastName).removeValidators([Validators.required])
 
})
```

now when value of bool is changing the validators will be set accordingly